# Limit rows to return using dplyr collect with parquet data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, parquet, apache-arrow

I am looking to limit the number of rows that are returned from parquet files, hoping to use `dplyr::collect`. I am aware that `head()` can be used to limit the number of rows, however I believe collecting all the rows is required first. I have seen `dplyr::collect(n=10)` used with databases, but am unable to make this work with parquet files. Some of the parquets I am working with has millions of rows, looking for an efficient option. Here are code snippets used this far:

**Method that returns a limited number of rows**

```
arrow::open_dataset(source = "C:/data/parquet/members") %>%
  dplyr::collect() %>%
  head(1000)
```

**Method that does not return a limited number of rows**

```
arrow::open_dataset(source = "C:/data/parquet/members") %>%
  dplyr::collect(n=1000)
```

**UPDATE**
The following works, is there a more efficient method?

```
head(arrow::open_dataset(sources = "C:/data/parquet/members"), 1000) %>%
  dplyr::collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you have discovered:

```
head(arrow::open_dataset(sources = "C:/data/parquet/members"), 1000) %>%
  dplyr::collect()
```

is the best way to solve this problem.  You want to apply the `head` operation before the `collect` operation.  This should not read in the entire dataset and should be efficient.

Note: while it will always return 1000 rows it may have to read in slightly more than that given readahead configuration & row group sizes in your parquet files.

Note2: there can be some cases where you get surprising and/or non-deterministic results: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13893